# Test array of sub strings against a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, user-agent

I have an array of bot names. When a user or bot visits my site, I get the `user-agent` and want to test if one of the values in my array exists in it.

```
var bots = [
  "twitterbot",
  "linkedinbot",
  "facebookexternalhit",
  "pinterest",
  "dotbot", 
  "rogerbot",
  "googlebot",
  "baiduspider",
  "yahoo! slurp",
  "bot",
  "spider",
  "simplepie",
  "yahooseeker",
  "embedly",
  "quora link preview",
  "outbrain",
  "vkshare",
  "monit",
  "pingability",
  "monitoring",
  "winhttprequest",
  "apache-httpclient",
  "getprismatic.com",
  "python-requests",
  "twurly",
  "yandex",
  "browserproxy",
  "webmeup-crawler",
  "qwantify"
];

var isBot = function(agent){
  return bots.some(function(bot){
    return bot.test(agent);      
  });
}

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var test = isBot(req.get("user-agent").toLowerCase());
  console.log(test);
});
```

This gives me the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

What's going wrong here?
Bonus points if you can help me expand this bots list by pointing me to a helpful external link or suggesting some yourself!

Comment: Bonus points, a nice one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` function is not available on Strings, but on RegExp objects. Therefore, you need to define your blacklisted items as RegExps, not strings:

```js
    var bots = [
      /twitterbot/,
      /linkedinbot/,
      /facebookexternalhit/,
      /pinterest/,
      /dotbot/,
      /rogerbot/,
      /googlebot/,
      /baiduspider/,
      /yahoo! slurp/,
      /bot/,
      /spider/,
      /simplepie/,
      /yahooseeker/,
      /embedly/,
      /quora link preview/,
      /outbrain/,
      /vkshare/,
      /monit/,
      /pingability/,
      /monitoring/,
      /winhttprequest/,
      /apache-httpclient/,
      /getprismatic.com/,
      /python-requests/,
      /twurly/,
      /yandex/,
      /browserproxy/,
      /webmeup-crawler/,
      /qwantify/
    ];
    
    var isBot = function(agent){
      return bots.some(function(bot){
        return bot.test(agent);      
      });
    };

alert('"clean-user-agent" is bot? ' + isBot('clean-user-agent'));
alert('"the ***twitterbot***" is bot? ' + isBot('the ***twitterbot***'));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var bots = [
  /twitterbot/,
  /linkedinbot/,
  /facebookexternalhit/,
  /pinterest/,
  /dotbot/,
  /rogerbot/,
  /googlebot/,
  /baiduspider/,
  /yahoo! slurp/,
  /bot/,
  /spider/,
  /simplepie/,
  /yahooseeker/,
  /embedly/,
  /quora link preview/,
  /outbrain/,
  /vkshare/,
  /monit/,
  /pingability/,
  /monitoring/,
  /winhttprequest/,
  /apache-httpclient/,
  /getprismatic.com/,
  /python-requests/,
  /twurly/,
  /yandex/,
  /browserproxy/,
  /webmeup-crawler/,
  /qwantify/
];
var isBot = function(agent){
  for(var b in bots) {
    if(bot[b].test(agent)) {
      return true;
    }     
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Comment: holly [$he-humus](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a1/you-dont-mess-with-the-zohan-script.html) that's a loooooottttt of regex, bad practice much?